# How to mention a property in PHPDoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I am trying to mention a property of my class somewhere else in other comments of my class, ie. in a method of that class.

For example if we have this code:

(please search for: `property $mention -- @property Village::mention does not work`)

```
class Village {
    /**
     * @var array Data container.
     */
    public $data = [];

    /**
      *
      */
    public $mention = 'Me';

    /**
     * Village constructor which injects data.
     *
     * @param $data
     */
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * A factory for our Villages.
     * 
     * @return Village
     */
    public static function hillbilly() {
        return new Village;
    }

    /**
     * Name tells the story...
     *
     * Now somewhere at this exact point I want to mention the
     * $mention property -- @property Village::mention does not work
     * nor does @property $mention either...
     *
     * @return array Rednecks unset.
     */
    public function redneck() {
        if(sizeof($data)) {
            unset($data);
        }

        return $data;
    }
}

$countryside = [
    'important' => 'data',
    'axe' => 'knifes',
    'shovel' => 'hoe',
    'trowel' => 'mixer',
];

$village = Village::hillbilly($countryside);
```

How do I make a mention of a property in PHPDoc?

Comment: What is the purpose of mentioning?

Comment: you could use the @see annotation. Generally it does not matter what you use, as long as it is human readable (IDE's usually get it either way)

Comment: Refer to something briefly and without going into detail. Like `@see` for methods.

Comment: Yes, anyways, `@see` is the way to go. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to have the `$mention` in the docblock text, one would usually use the inline see `{@see element description}`:

```
/**
 * Name tells the story...
 *
 * Now somewhere at this exact point I want to mention the
 * {@see Village::$mention} property.
 *
 * @return array Rednecks unset.
 * @see Village::$mention
 * @uses Village::$mention
 */
public function redneck() {
    if(sizeof($data)) {
        unset($data);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

The `@see` or `@uses` standalone tags are also available, but not for embedding the link into the docblock narrative text.

Note that older phpDocumentor only allowed the inlink link tag `{@link url|element description}`.